# Finding solutions to equations in $Z_{143}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would you find all solutions to the equation $x^2=3$ in $Z_{143}$?

I don't really know where to start.

Comment: why downvote this question ?, its good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2\equiv3\pmod{143}$$

$$\iff x^2\equiv3\pmod{11}\text{ and }x^2\equiv3\pmod{13}$$

As $11,13$ are small moduli,

by observation, $\displaystyle x\equiv\pm4\pmod{13}, \equiv\pm5\pmod{11}$

As $(11,13)=1,$  apply [CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html)